# Can a MetaData object have true values for both the IsFile / IsFolder and IsDelete properties?

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox, dropbox-api

Using the [Dropbox .NET SDK for the v2 API](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet), can a file/folder [MetaData object](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/Properties_T_Dropbox_Api_Files_Metadata.htm) have both the IsFile/IsFolder property set to true along with the IsDeleted property?  Or are these three properties mutually exclusive.

For example, if a file was deleted, would the code in the if statement be executed:

```
    ListFolderResult listFolderResult = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty);
    Metadata metaData = listFolderResult.Entries.ElementAt(0);
    if(metaData.IsFile && metaData.IsDeleted)
    {
        // could this occur
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three are mutually exclusive. A good tip is to check out the HTTP documentation: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-files-list_folder. If you expand the definition of Metadata there, you'll see that it's always just one of those three subtypes:

> Metadata (datatype with subtypes)
>
> Metadata for a file or folder.
>
> This datatype will be one of the following subtypes:
>
> - file FileMetadata
> - folder FolderMetadata
> - deleted DeletedMetadata